# Am I using memcpy wrong?

Tags: c, memcpy, bit-fields

I'm trying to use memcpy to copy part of an unsigned int to another unsigned int within the same struct I made. But my program only prints the first printf statement and then says: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
Am I using memcpy wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct time
    {
        unsigned int hours:5;
        unsigned int minutes:6;
        unsigned int seconds:6;
    };

    struct time t = {0x10,0b101011,45};

    printf("The time is : %d:%d:%d\n", t.hours, t.minutes, t.seconds);

    memcpy(t.minutes, t.seconds, 2);

    printf("The time is : %d:%d:%d\n", t.hours, t.minutes, t.seconds);

    return 0;
}
```

I've already done `t.minutes = t.seconds` and that copies the whole number, but I only want a portion of it.

Comment: memcpy takes an address, not an integer - I'm surprised you didn't get a segmentation fault. And what on earth do you mean, copy PART of a number? Numbers don't have parts.

Comment: @torstenvl - 0xc00005 is microsoft speak for segmentation fault

Comment: please explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: `memcpy` operates on bytes. This will not work on bitfields the way you might think. Simply `t.minutes = t.seconds;` is sufficient if you want to copy the value of .seconds into .minutes.

Comment: I'm using windows, so that might be the problem. When I say part of number I mean I'm trying to copy the most significant 2 bits of the unsigned int.

Comment: Use `unsigned int temp:2` and assign it a value by masking off the high two bits. `temp = (t.seconds & 0b110000) >> 4` Then assign similarly: `t.minutes = (temp << 4) | (t.minutes & 0b001111)`

Comment: Why not just 
```
t.minutes = t.minutes || (t.seconds * 0x
```

Comment: @paddy - Oh ok. Is there a way I can copy the most significant 2 bits from t.seconds to t.minutes if I can't use memcpy?

Comment: @torstenvl please see my answer for how to correctly perform masked bitwise copies. Your method is not even valid C. You cannot define bitfields outside of a struct. Even without attempting that, your code hides the symmetry of the operation, disguising half of it with shifts. That makes it harder to read and maintain. It is also not extensible to copying arbitrary non-sequential patterns of bits. Note that binary literals are a GNU extension, not standard C.

Comment: Bit-fields are not simply `unsigned int` values.  You can't take the address of a bit-field, so you cannot use `memmove()` or `memcpy()` with them.  There are lots of special rules associated with bit-fields — see the standard for the sordid (and hard to comprehend) details: [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1) — [¶4ff](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p4), [¶9ff](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your clarification in the comments:

> When I say part of number I mean I'm trying to copy the most significant 2 bits of the unsigned int.

The way to copy individual bits is by doing bit manipulation with bitwise operators.

The two most significant bits in your 6-bit fields are therefore represented by the value 0x30 (110000 in binary). To copy these from one to another, simply clear out those bits in the destination, then mask the source and combine with bitwise-OR:

```
unsigned int mask = 0x30;
t.minutes = (t.minutes & ~mask) | (t.seconds & mask);
```

Breakdown of the above:

- `~mask` inverts the mask, meaning that bits 4 and 5 will be 0 and all other bits will be 1
- this value is then ANDed with `minutes`, resulting in clearing bits 4 and 5
- the opposite occurs when ANDing the mask with `seconds`, resulting in *only* bits 4 and 5 being preseved, and all other bits cleared
- the two values are then combined with OR and assigned to `minutes`